# Exchange automation, event grouping and reporting?.. through SharePoint or something else

Tags: sharepoint, api, interface, project, exchange-server

Does native exchange offer this functionality? If not can we build an interface from SharePoint or something else to Exchange to meet this requirement? How about other products out there?

Requirements:

1. A user interface that enables you (the schedulers) to schedule events in Outlook that automatically schedules a preset number  related tasks (more calendar events) prior to the principal event.  An executive group will get an Outlook event invite to the principal event and  staff will get invites to all the related tasks.   Dates for related tasks will be generated automatically and factor in weekends and holidays.
2. A user interface that enables you (the schedulers) to see and filter by event in a way  that lists all related tasks, participants and accept/decline status.

The interface for all participants must be Exchange and all participatns must receive exchange invitaions and meeting alert notifications as they do today for other Exchange calendar events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use SharePoint OWA (outlook web access) web parts, I think they have all your requirements, if not you need to develop you requirement using Exchange Web Services

Comment: Thanks. I am able to access OWS directly via a browser - though it does prompt for security, but when I attempt to access a calendar from one for those webparts I get a 404 error.

Comment: This worked! would you know if there is OWA query string that enable us to see only select Calendar Categories? Thanks.

Comment: Possible to expand on the question.  Can we implement master categories in Exchange with set colors that automatically appear on all outlook users and clients?

Comment: Also, possible to filter OWA calendar webpart by a set view that filters on category? Thanks.